# How do you get a different version from GAC

Tags: c#

Suppose I have released an application that uses an assembly that is in the GAC.

At a later date, I have a new version of the assembly. Do I remove the original version and install the new one or do I install the new one and make sure the application references it (via version numbers??).

What if I want older versions of the app to use the version they were installed with, whilst the new version of the application should use the new assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a publisher [binding policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309359%28VS.71%29.aspx) to specify the range of versions your app is allowed to use. You can upgrade the policy with each new release. Do not uninstall old versions (unless they are very bad).

Answer (score 4):

If you have an assembly in the GAC and you release a new one with different version numbers you should also store that one in the GAC as well.  One of the primary functions of the GAC is to allow different versions of the same assembly to exist in a global location.

All of your projects should reference the assembly with the appropriate version and the CLR will take care of loading the correct one for you.

Comment: So there is no concept of "if I do not find the version I was looking for, get the next highest version"?

Comment: JD: No, w/o a policy it will only load with the exact same assembly.

Comment: Henk: As JaredPar and you explained, the exact version is loaded. I now introduce a new version of the library, put it in the GAC. If I want my existing clients to use it, I need to have a policy file? How do I do this? Does this mean all my clients will need to be changed?

Comment: Just had a look a Binding Policy. So all I would need to do is put the XML file with the clients and that should be it (the new assembly will be used). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, see the link in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for all you help (Henk and JaredPar)